# Autogenerated html from ajax, clickable jquery

Tags: jquery

I did an ajax request to my server and it returns some objects. For each object I print

```html
                var html = '<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 padmov">';
                html += '<div class="imgWrap" alt="'+movie.imdb+'">';
                html += '<img class="imgMovie" src="' + poster.Poster + '"/>';
                html += '<p class="imgDescription" alt="'+movie.imdb+'">' + movie.titel + '<br>'+movie.year+'<br>';
```

Now I want to make this div clickable. And it need to returns the movie.imdb as I click it. But since I've multiple of the same html div's I don't know how to do this. Any suggestions?

I tried to do it with:

```js
$(Divname).click(function(){
  alert('test');
  });
```

But it didn't work;

Comment: your HTML does not seem valid: some tags are not closed. Is that normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$(document).click("Divname", function (e) {
  alert(e.target.getAttribute('alt'));
});
```

Note that you cant use 'this' variable in event listener because this points to the 'document' object.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$(document).on('click', '<selector>', function(){
   //code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use this

```
$(Divname).click(function(){
  alert('test');
});
```

but this for if you add items with ajax to the dom

```
$(document).on("click", "Divname", function () {
  alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function(){
   console.log("DONE")
});
```

Hope it helped! :-)